# String.ToLowerInvariant not working in lambda expression

Tags: c#, regex, linq, lambda, invariants

When I use `ToLowerInvariant` or `ToUpperInvariant` they don't work in lambda expressions.

I get an exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToUpperInvariant()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I use these methods or how can I convert UTF8 characters inside lambda expressions to lower or upper case?

```
  var words = context.Words;

  if (words.Any(wr => wr.Orthography.ToUpperInvariant() == textRange.Text.ToUpperInvariant()))
```

Comment: Is `words` an IQueryable?

Comment: @Domysee, thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, I've deleted my answer because you shouldn't actually use it. `context.Words.ToList();` would retrieve *all* words, but you just need to know if any of them satisfies the constraint.